# Does a 403 error occur if there is no user-agent on the proxy network?

Tags: flutter, https, proxy, http-status-code-403, dio

Returns a 403 error code in the proxy network environment.

I'm using Flutter and I'm using a dio package for HTTP communication.

The program that was built was run in a network environment with Proxy.

I received a 403 error code.

'User-Agent' was not added to the header during HTTP communication.

If I don't put 'User-Agent' in the http header, will I get a 403 error code in the Proxy network environment?